# Producer properties in a kafka streams app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

In a kafka streams topology which produces data into multiple topics, is there a way to configure a single producer that produces into one of the output topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, other than `Produced.with()` for setting serdes. You would need to separate out a separate topology and streamsconfig for that one topic, though you can refactor your DSL or Processor API calls to not duplicate much of the same logic.